# How to uppercase file name but exclude extension

Tags: linux, rename, file-rename

Is it possible to use `rename` to uppercase a file but exclude its extension?

ie:
I want to rename the file **foo_bar.ext** to **FOO_BAR.ext**

I tried with `rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' foo_bar.ext`, but the whole file (including extension) gets uppercased  **FOO_BAR.EXT**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking `rename` to convert all the instances of `[a-z]` to `[A-Z]`.  Instead, capture the desired string into a group and modify it:

```
rename 's/([^.]*)/\U$1/' foo_bar.ext
```

This would rename the file `foo_bar.ext` to `FOO_BAR.ext`.

---

If you have a file `foo_bar.baz.ext` that needs to be renamed to `FOO_BAR.BAZ.ext`, use greedy match and multiple groups.  Saying:

```
rename 's/(.*)(\..*)/\U$1\E$2/' foo_bar.baz.ext
```

would rename the file `foo_bar.baz.ext` to `FOO_BAR.BAZ.ext`.

Comment: I'm confused. Why isn't `rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' foo_bar.ext` a perfectly valid way to rename the file to uppercase? From the man page "To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use" `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`

Comment: @BroSlow Because the case for the extension needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead:

```
rename 's/.+(?=\.)/\U$&/g' *
```

**Example**:

```
$ ls
input.foo.bar.txt

$ rename 's/.+(?=\.)/\U$&/g' *
$ ls
INPUT.FOO.BAR.txt
```

Comment: I had to add -f probably because case insensitive file system